# Index of same name in two different domains

Tags: database, grails, indexing

I have two domain `Favorite` and `Post` and want to add `index` on these two domain. Following is the way I am dong this:

```
class Favorite {
    String name
    static mapping = {
        name column: 'name', index: 'name'
    }
}
```

and

```
class Post {
    String name
    Integer nbrOfFavorites
    static mapping = {
        name column: 'name', index: 'name'
    }
}
```

And when running the application I am getting following error in console:

```
ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: create index name on post (name)
ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - Index "NAME" already exists; SQL statement: create index name on post (name) [42111-176]
```

This code is crating index successfully for first domain (Favorite) but not for second domain (Post).

I searched for this and [as per this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352055/same-index-name-for-two-tables) we can have same index name for different tables. **Then why I am getting this error?**

**How can I create index of same name in different domains?**

- Grails version: 2.3.9 (also tried with v2.4.4)
- Database: H2

Ref# [Database Indices](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#databaseIndices)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're referencing a post about MySQL which allows reusing index names in different tables, but H2 doesn't - names must be unique across all tables. The index name isn't very important - you almost never refer to it directly. The query optimizer uses them to make querying more efficient, but that's just an implementation detail.

I'd go with prefixing the index name with the table name:

```
name column: 'name', index: 'favorite_name'
```

and

```
name column: 'name', index: 'post_name'
```

and optionally prefixing or suffixing to make it obvious that it's an index, e.g.

```
name column: 'name', index: 'idx_favorite_name'
```

and

```
name column: 'name', index: 'idx_post_name'
```